# Not getting current location in Android version 6.0

Tags: location

It's working fine in a 5.1.1 device or another device but getting the current location is not working in my Nexus 5 with the version 6.0 update.

Answer (score 0):

Marshmallow does not read permission from your menifest.xml file. you have to give permission programmatically.

```
  public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

hope it will works.